# Jenkins Pipeline sh command working with output and raising errors

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I am using Jenkins Pipeline as the orchestration system for a moderately complex build and deployment pipeline. I am a novice at Groovy and despite stumbling my way through, and finding a work around, I feel like there must be a reasonably straightforward to accomplish the following.

Assume I have some Ruby file:

```
def some_method(x, y)
  fail StandardError if x == "cat"
  puts "i love #{x} and #{y}"
end

some_method ARGV[0], ARGV[1]
```

I want to run the pipeline shell command `sh` and have it exhibit the following behavior (I'm using pseudo rspec to convey the desire):

```
describe "When I run a Jenkins Pipeline shell command" do
  subject { sh "ruby config/deploy/some_script.rb ${x} ${y}" }
  let(:x) { "foo" }
  let(:y) { "bar" }
  context "when the shell command has a 0 return code" do
    it "is the stdout from the shell command execution" do
      expect(subject).to eq "i love foo and bar"
    end
  end
  context "when the shell has a non-zero return code" do
    let(:x) { "cat" }
    it "raises a Jenkins Pipeline error" do
      expect(subject).to invoke groovy_jenkins_pipeline_command_error
    end
  end
end
```

What actually happens is that the return code is always returned by the sh command and I cannot access the stdout directly. I can pipe the stdout to /dev/null, but then I get a munged return value which contains the return code, the output I do want, and other stdout that I don't really care about.

*ideally* I wouldn't even have to call puts in the Ruby code, instead I could just let the code return the result and have it passed through to the groovy runtime.

I also have this problem with invoking the AWS eb cli client inside of a Jenkins Pipeline sh command.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by telling the shell to grab the standard output:

```
myRubyScript="ruby config/deploy/some_script.rb ${x} ${y}"
def returncode=sh script: "$myRubyScript", returnStdout: true
```